# Question: Use a factor's index to plot variables

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm very new to R so I'm sorry if this is something really simple.
I've had a look on a bunch of cheat sheets and can't see anything obvious.

I have a simple set of data that has date, temperature, and 4 different factors (based on the bloom of a tree // 1 = "", 2 = "bloom", 3 = "full", 4 = "scatter")

What I want to do, but have no idea how, is to do a scatter plot of the date and temperature of each factor individually.

Comment: plot (data$date, data$temperature), hope this will solve your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `ggplot2` with `facet_wrap`. First, be sure to set the level names of the `Bloom` factor so the plots will label usefully.

Then, we use `ggplot` to plot the data and `group =` by the `Bloom` factor. Then we add `facet_wrap` with the formula that `.` (everything else) should be grouped by `Bloom`.

```
library(ggplot2)
levels(TreeData$Bloom) <- c("None","Bloom","Full","Scatter")

ggplot(TreeData, aes(x=Date,y=Temp,group = Bloom, color = Bloom)) +
   geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + 
   facet_wrap(. ~ Bloom)
```

[image]

Per your comment, if you wanted individual graphs you could use base R subsetting with `TreeData[TreeData$Bloom == "Full",]`. Note that "Full" is the factor level we set earlier.

```
ggplot(TreeData[TreeData$Bloom == "Full",], aes(x=Date,y=Temp)) +
  geom_point() + labs(title="Full Bloom")
```

[image]

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
TreeData <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq.Date(from=as.Date("2019-04-01"), to = as.Date("2019-08-01"), by = "week"),each = 10) , Temp = round(runif(22,38,n=180)), Bloom = as.factor(sample(1:4,180,replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can these be plotted as individual graphs rather than all together as a figure?
I don't care about the "None" and don't want to analyse that at all.

Comment: I edited my answer with your requested single plot.